# graphical visualisation of twitter data - using processing java

Tags: java, twitter, processing

can someone give some examples of how I can show a graphical visualisation of twitter data using animation.

http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/2009/more-truth-about-twitter/
http://flowingdata.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/06/50-great-examples-of-data-visualization/